# Unable to Get Types if Parent is Optional

Tags: typescript

I would like the type `ShowOptions` to be `"ALL" | "ACTIVE" | "DRAFT"`

But instead I'm seeing the error `TS2339: Property show does not exist on type`

Any ideas how I can extract `ShowOptions`?  Note that I don't have control over the `QueryParameters` type - it's automatically generated from an OpenAPI spec.

```js
// Snippet of generated TypeScript code from an OpenAPI definition - I have no control over this code!
type QueryParameters = {
  query?: {
    show: "ALL" | "ACTIVE" | "DRAFT";
  };
};

type Query = QueryParameters["query"];
type ShowOptions = Query["show"]; // TS2339: Property show does not exist on type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to wrap `Query` in `NonNullable<T>`

```
// Snippet of generated TypeScript code from an OpenAPI definition - I have no control over this code!
type QueryParameters = {
  query?: {
    show: "ALL" | "ACTIVE" | "DRAFT";
  };
};

type Query = QueryParameters["query"];
type ShowOptions = NonNullable<Query>["show"];
```